# Convert orange pickle file to csv

Tags: python

I want to convert my pickle file to csv. I'm able to convert csv to pkl and again pkl to csv but I couldn't convert orange pkl file to csv.

```
> pickle = read_pickle_file(""C://Users//HP//Desktop//Meena program//Data Mining.pkl")
Error: unexpected symbol in "pickle = read_pickle_file(""C"
> pickle = read_pickle_file("C://Users//HP//Desktop//Meena program//Data Mining.pkl")
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orangecontrib'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your path according to the error message. You have a double quote in your C: path.

Instead of writing `""C:/ ..."` your path should look like this: `"C:/ ..."`. And depending on the system, you should also see if double `//` are designed and suitable for your system.

And for your second error you should install the associated Orange libraries via `pip3 install Orange3-Associate`

Comment: In tried the above cmnds. But I couldn't find out the solution